# date time with timezone

Tags: date, time, google-bigquery, zone

The date/time strings we're sending over to pub/sub look like this:

```
2018-07-18T17:30:08Z
```

I created a data flow job to insert these into Big Query and it failed at insert.

Stripping out the "Z" at the end like this was successful:
`2018-07-18T17:30:08`

The problem is that Big Query seems to be interpreting this as a local time, and not UTC.

I've tried both of these ways to insert the time zone:

```
2018-07-18T17:30:08+00:00
2018-07-18T17:30:08+0000
```

Both are rejected.

What's the correct way to do this, or is there some other way I can force Big Query to interpret these times as UTC?

Comment: Can you share code? BigQuery should be reading dates without a timezone as UTC - otherwise what local time would it guess?

Comment: Can you share the error message you are receiving? You have the explanation of Timestamp data type for [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type) and for [Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types). According to the document, for Standard SQL "when a time zone is not explicitly specified, the default time zone, UTC, is used."